# Making stop key for hashed partial keys in hbase

Tags: hbase

The `hbase` table has `CityName` and `ID` as composite keys. I made `rowkeys` as follows :

- MD5 hashing of `Cityname` and `ID` separately
- appending the hashed `ID` to the `Cityname`.

`Row key : MD5[CityName]MD5[ID]`

**Now, I would like to get all the rows with `CityName = "London"`.**

I tried to do partial scan but I did not understand how to make stop key. Or is there other way to get the all the rows with a specific city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that will probably work you:

```
Scan myScan = new Scan(Bytes.add("yourHashedCityName".getBytes() + Bytes.toBytes(0), Bytes.add("yourHashedCityName".getBytes() + Bytes.toBytes(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

Please notice that stopRow is exclusive, so, a row with an id of Integer.MAX_VALUE will be excluded.

If your ID is a 8 byte long replace 0 for 0L and Integer.MAX_VALUE for Long.MAX_VALUE :)

---

Anyway, I generally use 1 byte as separator (null) in my row keys containing hashes when it's evident I'm going to use them for scanning, somewhat like:

```
byte[] myRowkey = Bytes.add("first".getBytes() + "\0".getBytes() + "second".getBytes());
```

That way, I can easily do:

```
Scan myScan = new Scan(Bytes.add("first".getBytes() + "\0".getBytes()), "first".getBytes() + "\1".getBytes());
```

The scanner will start from `first\0` until `first\1` (a row that won't ever exist since I only use \0 as separator).

Answer (score 1):

Keys are stored in HBase in lexographic order.  So, if the MD5 hash of "London" is '1234', then you can get all keys that start with London, but scanning from '1234' to '1235' -- i.e. the start key is just your MD5 hash and the end key just increments the last byte of the first part of your key by 1